# Spark find key/value pairs with key equals to other values and join

Tags: scala, apache-spark

If we have the following key value pairs:

```
[T,V]  [V,W]  [A,B]  [B,C]
```

I need to result to be

```
[T,V]  [V,W]  [T,W]  [A,B]  [B,C]  [A,C]
```

So basically to generate [T,W] from [T,V] and [V,W] and append to the existing set

I'm not sure how to do this in spark with scala, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using purely Scala collection functions (in [Set](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.Set)) - I don't use Spark:

```
val ex = Set("T" -> "V", "V" -> "W", "A" -> "B", "B" -> "C")

val keysEquallingValues = ex.flatMap { tuple => 
  ex.find(t => tuple._2 == t._1).map(t => tuple -> t)
}
val r = ex ++ keysEquallingValues.map(pair => pair._1._1 -> pair._2._2)
```

Explanation:

`ex` is your example input `Set`

We `flatMap` over it, using an expression that returns an `Option[((String,String), (String, String))]` - i.e. if the condition *is there a tuple with a key the same as the current value?* is true, we'll have a `Some` containing a tuple of the two tuples (!) that satisfy the condition.

Using `flatMap` and `Option` like this allows us to drop out non-matching cases (like a `filter`) but also simultaneously transform the content of the collection in the one pass.

Finally we cherrypick the key of the first tuple and the value of the second, to get the desired combination, and add it to your original `Set`.

Answer (score 2):

```
val df = sc.parallelize(
  Array(("T","V"),("V","W"),("A","B"),("B","C"))
).toDF("key","value")

df.show
+---+-----+
|key|value|
+---+-----+
|  T|    V|
|  V|    W|
|  A|    B|
|  B|    C|
+---+-----+

df.join(
  df.toDF("keyR", "valueR"),
  $"value" === $"keyR"
).explode($"key",$"value",$"keyR",$"valueR"){row => Seq(
  (row.getString(0), row.getString(1)),
  (row.getString(2), row.getString(3)),
  (row.getString(0), row.getString(3))
)}.select($"_1" as "key", $"_2" as "value").show
+---+-----+
|key|value|
+---+-----+
|  A|    B|
|  B|    C|
|  A|    C|
|  T|    V|
|  V|    W|
|  T|    W|
+---+-----+
```